# Selection probability weight

Tags: survey, weighted-sampling

I have a question on my selection probability weight. Is it a correct weight?

***The research design:*** research areas were divided into strata according to size. Interviews were taken: 50 batches of 10 interviews in each area according to the relative size of strata. 
Clusters were made for each stratum. In each cluster: batches of 10 interviews were sampled in fixed intervals. A random walk selected households and within these households, respondents were randomly chosen.

***The selection probability weight:*** I had no population data on number of households. A selection probability weight was calculated for the within-household selection for each stratum. In each stratum, a weight was calculated and normalized so that the sum of the weights is 500 for each research area. The size of the eventual stratum was divided by the number of people in the stratum eligible for the survey. The result of this calculation was then multiplied by the number of eligible respondents in the household.

Comment: I will also be happy when it is well done :-D

Comment: No one knows. No survey specialists here :'-(.

Comment: Absolutely no survey specialists :D